# How to create a Windows service using sc MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp, windows-services, mariadb

I am trying to create a Windows service for a second instance of MySQL and I dont know what is wrong. This is my command:

```
sc create mysqlxampp binPath= "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file= "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini" mysqlxampp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sc delete MySQL56

sc create MySQL56 start= auto  DisplayName= MySQL56  binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe\" --defaults-file=\"C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini\" MySQL56"
```